# Saving images from sources without a specific mime type

Tags: php

As an example, say I'm trying to download App Icons from the Google Play store for a service. Here is an example URL:

https://lh6.ggpht.com/1eVPA6Iukw-F4i5xq1ZWicaKBzmprLGw98YhdG20E-wlsHHg3PcKJqbY_fWLdJeGRw=w512-rw

There is no mime type associated with the data provided, and when the file is saved any image viewers (or at least the ones I've tried) will say the file is corrupt. They will show up in Chrome and a couple of other things, but when inspecting the data, it's clear there's simply no mime type. This is an issue, because I am further using these data streams in other scripts which require that they be recognized as a specific type. (namely PNG)

I've tried things such as:

```
imagepng(imagecreatefromstring($icondata), $finaldir.'/icon.png');
```

Where $icondata is simply a curl response for the image. This will return an error saying that the data is of an unknown format for the imagecreatefromstring function. Of course, I've also tried:

```
file_put_contents($finaldir.'/icon.png', $icondata);
```

To no avail. It creates the file, but as I said, the image is not recognized as an image in most applications and in various analyzing functions. Is there a way to specifically set the mime type of a given string of data? Or some other workaround I'm not quite seeing?

Edit: Also, to note, there is nothing wrong with the $icondata variable. I have tried manually saving the image to a file through my web browser, and the same problem arises.

Comment: When I check the header as HTTP instead of HTTPS, I do see `Content-Type => image/webp` in the header response..

Comment: I see, thank you for that, I had not noticed earlier. After looking around, it seems like it's trivial to convert a png, jpeg, etc. to a webp image, but I'm not seeing anything about converting one back to a png. I'm still looking around, but any suggestions for me there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have developed a small CMS for myself and was facing the same issue. After trying a lot, I have found a solution. It is working for me and I hope you will find it useful for your project too.

Regarding the corruption of file, for Chrome user-agent, Google servers send icons as .webp format and you need a PHP library for handling images of this type. And for other user-agents (like Firefox), images are sent as PNG.

Now comparing the two URLs for a same icon in Firefox or Chrome, you will notice that image paths generated for Chrome contain `-rw` at the end while the same URL in Firefox doesn't contain that `-rw`.

Not digging very deeper, simply remove the `-rw` from the end of the URL and copy the image. You will get a PNG image. A hint is here for you:

```
<?php
    $image_path = "https://lh5.ggpht.com/8PODwBXKk4L201m4IO1wifRDfbn4Q1JxNxOzj-5TXPJ85_S-vOqntLi7TsVyeFQM0w4=w300-rw"; // Firefox app on Google Play
    $png_path = substr($image_path, 0, -3);
    copy($png_path, 'file.png');
?>
```

This will save the image as PNG. Please note that I have used `substr()` function to remove `-rw` from the end. To make it precise, you may use any other way to fix that part of the path.

P.S. You may also try sending a custom user-agent (i.e. Firefox) with your CURL request to receive the PNG path so you will not need to fix it by yourself :)

Comment: This was exactly what I was hoping for. In my frustration that Google would use something so different from everything else, I didn't even think that other browsers would clearly need to receive the image as a PNG. Thanks so much, this completely solved the issue for me.

Comment: Glad to know that it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpResponse::getContentType to determine type of content you're getting from URL

Answer (score 0):

This not a png, but `WebP`

You can use it in PHP with

```
imagecreatefromwebp( string $filename );
```

More information:
- https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/
- http://php.net/manual/function.imagecreatefromwebp.php